# WPF c# Relative Source Ancestor Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main window with a user control in a content control

```
<MainWindow Title="MainWindow">
<!-- MainWindows DataContext is set to MainWindowViewModel -->

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ViewModel1}">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContentControl/>
<MainWindow/>
```

And a User Control with a text box

```
<UserControl Title="UserControl1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Words}"/>
<UserControl/>
```

And a MainWindowViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set 
        { 
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    private string _words;

    public string Words
    {
        get { return _words; }
        set 
        { 
            _words = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Words");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I bind the textblocks text to the Words property?
I tried this but it isnt working...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.Words}" />
```

Comment: yes, I do mean that

Comment: As `UserControl` is a subclass of `ContentControl`, the RelativeSource will resolve to your UserControl. You could try specifying `AncestorLevel` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237037/wpf-relativesource-behavior).

Comment: Why do you set `<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">` when you want the UserControl to bind to a property of MainWindowViewModel? Try `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">`. The RelativeSource Binding is (again) pointless.

Comment: You would of course also need `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel}">`.

Comment: In case you have a UserControl that really simultaneously binds to different view models, consider a different approach. Instead of directly accessing the view models in the UserControl's XAML, let the control expose a set of bindable properties that would be bound to properties of different view models when you use the control, like `<local:UserControl1 Prop1="{Binding PropFromCurrentVm}" Words="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.Words}"/>`

Comment: @Clemens what is the advantage of doing that? wouldnt I have those bindings somewhere in the usercontrol anyway?

Comment: The UserControl would not have a dependency on the view model(s). It could be used with different view models.